# How can I create two new variables containing simple and weighted conditional means based on specific group rules in R?

Tags: conditional-statements, mean

I need creat two new variables containing simples mean and weighted mean.

```
id <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
var_1   <- c(1,2,3,7,4,0,7,7,0,1)
var_2   <- c(8,4,0,4,5,8,1,1,8,0)
var_3   <- c(4,5,6,8,6,0,1,5,8,4)
var_4   <- c(7,8,9,5,0,7,5,0,1,4)
var_5   <- c(2,3,4,2,0,1,0,8,7,1)
var_6   <- c(8,7,4,5,6,0,5,6,7,6)
var_7   <- c(1,0,9,1,5,4,0,7,4,4)
var_8   <- c(6,8,7,0,8,5,5,0,5,1)
var_9   <- c(4,4,9,7,4,7,2,8,1,0)
group   <- as.factor(c(1,2,3,5,6,4,3,1,1,2))


class(group)

df <- data.frame(id,var_1,var_2,var_3,var_4,var_5,var_6,var_7,
                 var_8,var_9,group) 

           
df

  id var_1 var_2 var_3 var_4 var_5 var_6 var_7 var_8 var_9 group
   1     1     8     4     7     2     8     1     6     4     1
   2     2     4     5     8     3     7     0     8     4     2
   3     3     0     6     9     4     4     9     7     9     3
   4     7     4     8     5     2     5     1     0     7     5
   5     4     5     6     0     0     6     5     8     4     6
   6     0     8     0     7     1     0     4     5     7     4
   7     7     1     1     5     0     5     0     5     2     3
   8     7     1     5     0     8     6     7     0     8     1
   9     0     8     8     1     7     7     4     5     1     1
  10     1     0     4     4     1     6     4     1     0     2
```

I have specific  rule to calculate means.

```
MEAN TYPE 1

If group == 1: mean(var_1:var3)
if group == 2: mean(var_1, var_5,var_9) or [(var_1+var_5+var_9)/3]
if group == 3: mean(var_5:var_8) or [(var_5+var_6+var_7+var_8)/4]
.
.
.
```

I have specific weight for each var_10 value, for instance:

```
MEAN TYPE 2

If group == 1, mean is: [(var_1*2)+(var_3*3) + (var_4*4)]/(2+3+4)

if group == 2, mean is: [(var_4)+(var_7*2) + (var_9*3)]/(1+3+4)

if group == 3, mean is: [(var_5*2)+(var_6*3) + (var_8*4)]/3

.

.

.
```

I'm beginner in R and I don't know a otimized code in R to MEAN TYPE 1.

Then, I tried one by one for after put together . But, I can't get indicate the factor variable like a contidional.

```
df <- df |>
dplyr:mutate(ms1 = mean(var_1:var_3),
         case_when(group==1))

It doesn't work. I've ran others changes, details...put if else... But, nothing. I don't know. 


The wanted result would be around like this:
```

```
   id var_1 var_2 var_3 var_4 var_5 var_6 var_7 var_8 var_9 group mean1 mean2
   1     1     8     4     7     2     8     1     6     4     1  4.33  4.67
   2     2     4     5     8     3     7     0     8     4     2  3.00  2.50
   3     3     0     6     9     4     4     9     7     9     3  6.00 16.00
   .
   .
   .
```

For MEAN TYPE 2  I don't know a otimized code too.

But, I would calculate one by one too, if I could solve how indicate var_10 (factor) specific value.

I appreciate any help!